# Authenticate users in my django app using an existing ASP.Net IdentityServer login app

Tags: django, oauth, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid

I'm trying to authenticate users in my django app using an existing ASP.Net IdentityServer login app. I've seen the documentation has an example for an angular or react(Javascript based app) but not django. Does anyone have some sample code or tutorial that shows how to do in django? I'm new at this. Especially when it comes to the call back. I'm not sure i need to use an open iD client package to do this. Is it possible to do this in django? Or does it have to be a JS application? I appreciate any assistance

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html?highlight=authority#add-your-html-and-javascript-files